# Position of elements in CSS

Tags: css

I've got annoying problem at website: https://www.kinderwagencenter.de/produkt/kombikinderwagen/karex-kamil/

Just point your mouse on big product thumbnail and you will see that the countdown is still on the top. How to make image thumbnail be on top every time?

Comment: Set the z-index of the zoomed view higher than the element's z-index that's containing the countdown.

Comment: Read how to write a question, this isn't the correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this I did this:

```
.counter-group {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Theres probably better ways, but this works!

Comment: Pretty sure this is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure the `z-index` is off in a couple of your css selectors.  Try changing to this.

```
.counter-block .counter .number.show {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
 }

.counter-block .counter .number.hidden-up {
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could set the z-index of the thumbnail to a high amount to get rid of the problem: z-index of counter --> z-index: -1; and z-index of thumbnail --> z-index: 1;